# Simplifying a limit with factorials... not sure how to cancel factorials: (2(n+1))! / (2n)!

Tags: calculus, limits

Wolfram says that $\displaystyle \frac{2(n+1))!}{(2n)!} = 2(n+1)(2n+1)$

I just don't see how to get to there though.I know that 2! equals 2, but I guess that I can't pull the 2! out of the parentheses (which would just cancel to one anyway).  How an I get from the left side of the equation to the right side?

Comment: Can you multiply out the first few terms of $(2n+2)!$ and $(2n)!$, and see that most of the terms cancel?

Comment: $(2(n+1))!=(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)\underbrace{(2n)(2n-1)\cdots2\cdot1}_{=(2n)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(2(n+1))!=(2n+2)!=1\times2\times\cdots\times 2n\times(2n+1)\times(2n+2)
=(2n)!\times(2n+1)\times(2n+2).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{( 2(n+1) )!}{(2n)!} = \frac{(2n+ 2)!}{(2n)!}= \frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{(2n)!} = (2n+2)(2n+1)= 2(n+1)(n+2)$

Note: I have used $n ! = n (n-1)!$

Comment: (2n+1)(2n+1) =  2(n+1)(n+2)?  = (2n+2)(n+2) != (2n+2)(2n+1)  Can you help me understand that last part?

Comment: i have taken $2$ out from $(2n+2)$ so it is $
2(n+1)$